# Can I mark more than one field as @indexed in single document in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I am using **@indexed** annotation in my document for the person while using spring boot and MongoDb.

I have already marked **firstName** to be used for indexing.

Can I mark other fields as well for index?
The document is as mentioned below:

```
@Document
public class Person {
@Id private String id;
@Indexed(name = "first_name_index", direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING)
private String firstName;
private String secondName;
private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth
}
```

Is it a good practice to mark more than one field as indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can index multiple fields as `@Indexed` if your queries are orthogonal.

1. You need to support `findByFirstName` and `findByDateOfBirth` queries.

- you add `@Indexed` annotation to `firstName`
- you add `@Indexed` annotation to `dateOfBirth`

2. You need to support `findByFirstName` and `findByFirstNameAndDateOfBirth` queries.

- you add `@CompoundIndex(def = "{'findByFirstName': 1, 'dateOfBirth': 1}")` to `public class Person`.

Comment: Is it good practice to use more than one field for indexing?